# JavaScript Request Sent Continuously (Misbehaviour)

Tags: javascript, promise

We are facing a problem with our javascript application. We have the following method in an Angular 1.5 application. This method sometimes when called continues to run indefinitely. We have encountered situations where the function has continued to run and send requests to the server for hours and found the requests up to 4000.

How to make sure that the request is sent only once?

```js
var normalVisitAuthorization = function(cardNo) {
  $scope.authorizePromise =
    $q.all([VerificationService.authorizeCardWithVisit(cardNo, $scope.logininfo.FacilityCode, $scope.logininfo.UserName, $scope.visitType.selected.TypeID, 1), VerificationService.getLastVisits(cardNo)])
    .then(function(results) {
      console.log(results[0]);
      if (results[0].CardExistence.indexOf('MISSING') != -1) {
        $scope.memberDetails = undefined;
        DevExpress.ui.notify({
          message: 'The card was not found in NHIF Database. The 
          beneficiary should submit the card to the nearby NHIF office
          for
          verification ', 
          position: {
            my: "center center",
            at: "center center"
          }
        }, "warning", 7500);
      } else {
        $scope.memberDetails = results[0];
        $rootScope.memberDetails = results[0];
        $scope.lastVisits = results[1];
      }


      $scope.imageSrc = ngAuthSettings.verificationUrl + "GetImage?CardNo=" + cardNo;
      console.log($scope.imageSrc);

    }, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      DevExpress.ui.notify({
        message: error.data.ExceptionMessage,
        position: {
          my: "center center",
          at: "center center"
        }
      }, "warning", 4500);

    });

}
```

Comment: Could you please try to format your code in such a way that it is at least readable?

Comment: How is this function called/bound ?

Comment: You are using angular and you have to know about digest cycle of angular.